# how to get the progress percentage with Pace.JS

Tags: jquery, pace

I am using pace.js to load my website. But i dont want to use pace.js themes. I want to built my theme.

Is there a way that i can get de progress with jquery?

I know only this funciotns:

```
Pace.on("start", function(){
});
Pace.on("done", function(){
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this at line 296:

```
Pace.trigger('update', this.progress);
```

Then get like this:

```
Pace.on("update", function(percent){
});
```

Comment: Found myself visiting this exact answer multiple times. Pace could really add this nice feature.

Answer (score 2):

I've done like that

```js
Pace.bar.update = function(prog) {
    Pace.trigger('update', prog)
    this.progress = prog;
    return this.render();
} // override update func to trigger 'update' event
```

and later

```js
Pace.on('update', progress => {
    console.log('progress -> ', progress);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In `v1.2.4`, PaceJS fires the `progress` event - unfortunately not yet documented. Source code: https://github.com/CodeByZach/pace/blob/v1.2.4/pace.js#L297

So we can bind into this event like that:

```js
Pace.on('progress', function (progress) {
  console.log('Current progres:  ', progress);
});
```

Output example

```
Current progres:   7.033010570385887
Current progres:   36.033545715865465
Current progres:   51.343614294233035
Current progres:   67.08097906736533
Current progres:   76.40341932303679
Current progres:   91.56289986667561
Current progres:   100
```